# Unrecognized options on stripes

Tags: symfony, paypal, stripe-payments, sylius, payum

I'm trying to install and to configure Stripe for my web application. 
I have to use Sylius 0.18.0.
I installed Stripe with this tuto : http://sylius-older.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/stripe.html  (I also tried the version 4.8)

However I've an issue :

> Fatal error: **Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException' with message 'Unrecognized options "factory, secret_key, publishable_key, payum.template.layout, payum.template.obtain_token" under "payum.gateways.stripe_checkout"**' in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.php:317 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/BaseNode.php(264): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode->normalizeValue(Array) #1 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/PrototypedArrayNode.php(283): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\BaseNode->normalize(Array) #2 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/BaseNode.php(264): Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\PrototypedArrayNode->normalizeValue(Array) #3 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.php(307): Symfony\Component\Config\Defini in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/ArrayNode.php on line 317

***Config.yml :***

```
payum:
    gateways:
        stripe_checkout:
            factory: stripe_checkout
            secret_key: "%stripe.secret_key%"
            publishable_key: "%stripe.publishable_key%"
            payum.template.layout: SyliusShopBundle::Checkout/layout.html.twig
            payum.template.obtain_token: SyliusPayumBundle::Action/Stripe/obtainCheckoutToken.html.twig
```

I've got same issues when I try to configure paypal.

I tried a lot of "solutions" but the issues are stilling here ...
Thanks for your times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
payum:
gateways:
    paypal:
        paypal_express_checkout_nvp:
            username:  %paypal.express_checkout.username%
            password:  %paypal.express_checkout.password%
            signature: %paypal.express_checkout.signature%
            sandbox: true

    stripe:
        stripe_checkout:
            publishable_key: %stripe.publishable_key%
            secret_key: %stripe.secret_key%
    omnipay:
        omnipay:
            type: Stripe
            options:
                apiKey:  %stripe.secret_key%
                testMode: true
```

However the option Stripe isn't present in the dropdown list to choose the payment method